# How to open chrome standalone window in extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome browser action extension. I want to be able to open chrome standalone window when i click a button in default action. How can I do that? And how can I stablish a communication between default action and the window?

Comment: See chrome.windows.create and [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Thank you for response but I want to be able to open chrome application window and not a browser tab. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am actually looking for something like chrome.app.window.create() which I can call from extension popup or event page

Comment: Use chrome.windows.create and specify an html file from your extension directory. You can also set the `type`.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you very much. I used popup type and it works fine.